# Kill Bill ending Q & U. What does that mean?

Tags: credits, kill-bill

What is the meaning of

> Based on the character of 'The Bride' created by Q and U

that appears at the end of the film?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From [**IMDB:**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0266697/trivia)

> The closing title card, "Based on the character of 'The Bride' created by Q and U", refers to the first initials of Quentin Tarantino and Uma Thurman.

Comment: So does that mean, tarantino and thurman wrote the script of kill bill?

Comment: Aye, also from IMDB:  Writing credits
Quentin Tarantino   (written by)

Quentin Tarantino   (character The Bride) (as Q) &
Uma Thurman   (character The Bride) (as U)

Comment: It means what it says: The character of "The Bride" (which was played by Uma Thurman) was created by Quentin and Uma.  The *script* is completely different matter.

Answer (score 15):

It refers to (Q)uentin Tarantino and (U)ma Thurman. They actually thought of the idea together while filming Pulp Fiction.  In the diner, Uma's character is telling John Travolta's character about a TV show she was in...

Go 2 mins in.

According to DVD commentary, Uma and Quentin then chatted and created the bride.

From IMDb: "According to Quentin Tarantino and Uma Thurman in the DVD documentary the idea for doing "Kill Bill" began during the filming of Pulp Fiction (1994). The two began talking about the kinds of movies that they would like to do and Quentin said he would like to do a 70's style kung-fu flick. Uma came up with the film's opening shot of her beaten up and wearing a wedding gown."