# Is Mia Wallace (Uma Thurman) from Pulp Fiction the same person as The Bride in Kill Bill?

Tags: character, pulp-fiction, kill-bill

I was watching Pulp Fiction tonite and I suddenly realized that Uma's character makes reference to her failed pilot, Fox Force Five, and her character's prowess with knives.  It made me think of her role in Kill Bill, and the Deadly Viper Assassination Squad.  And since they're both Tarantino movies, and he has stated in the past that some of his characters are related, I started to wonder if Kill Bill could be considered a movie that exists within the Pulp Fiction universe, or if they're related in some way.

Comment: Related to [How many Tarantino films are set in the same universe?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10004/how-many-tarantino-films-are-set-in-the-same-universe).

Comment: The description Mia gives of Fox Force 5, is exactly like The Deadly Viper Assassination Squad: "There was a blonde one, Sommerset O'Neal from that show "Baton Rouge, she was the leader. A Japanese one, a black one, a French one and a brunette one, me. We all had special skills. Sommerset had a photographic memory, the Japanese fox was a kung fu master, the black girl was a demolition expert, the French fox' specialty was sex...".

Answer (score 9):

In my opinion, the answer is "certainly not". The Pulp fiction [wiki](http://pulpfiction.wikia.com/wiki/Mia_Wallace) for Mia & the Kill Bill [wiki](http://killbill.wikia.com/wiki/Beatrix_Kiddo) for Beatrix Kiddo state no connection at all. In spite of that there is large difference in the two characters as well. Mia Wallace is a cocaine addict whereas there is no indication anywhere that Beatrix uses any kind of drugs. The character that Mia Wallace played in that failed pilot was an expert with knives not Mia Wallace herself. Also going by the characters' ages Mia Wallace is around 10 years younger than Beatrix kiddo. Kiddo was a trained fighter, but Mia is much younger and the context that you are trying to indicate is that Mia was already trained at that time and had left the Viper assassination squad, but this seems highly unlikely.

Adding more info wrt Ben Plont's comment :
Fox Force 5 is fictional in Pulp Fiction. Fox Force 5 does not actually exist while Pulp Fiction is taking place. Relating these two would be like "there is a fictional show that is in the Pulp Fiction universe and then later in that same universe this story became true, meaning Fox Force 5 became an actual thing and the fictional character that Mia was playing became an actual character", Come on!! that wouldn't make sense. What I think is that Tarantino had this kind of idea (Fox Force 5) back in 1994 and which he used as a fictional TV show in Pulp Fiction and later developed that same idea into a full fledged movie as kill Bill. But Mia and Beatrix are definitely not the same girls.

Comment: Wiki, of course, is not always 100% accurate and has been compromised or filled with incorrect information many times.

Comment: Of course, but anyways I don't see any similarities between the two characters. Mia is in her 20s and Beatrix is in her 30s. Before Beatrix is assaulted, she had been working as an assassin for years, before that she was training in China for years, even before that she was with Bill. So if we keep going back in Beatrix's timeline we don't see any chances of her being Mia Wallace at some point in her life. But that's my own opinion.

Comment: Mia was PLAYING Beatrix as an actress.  Kill Bill, I have read, is a movie that exists in the Pulp Fiction universe; as in, a character from Pulp Fiction could go to a movie and see Kill Bill on the screen.

Comment: So if Kill Bill is a movie in Pulp Fiction universe, that means Beatrix's character is fictional. If Kill Bill and Pulp Fiction are in the same universe and both are true stories not movies, even then Beatrix and Mia are not the same characters. Tarantino has stated that some of his characters are related, but Beatrix and Mia are not related or at least there is no evidence of it. from whatever we know of the two characters we can deduce that it is rather unlikely that the two characters are same, which what I have mentioned in my answer.

Comment: "whereas there is no indication anywhere that Beatrix uses any kind of drugs" Beatrix is a deeply troubled person. No one becomes an assassin (or even just violent in general) because their life is filled with joy and happiness. There is no proof that she used drugs, but there is proof of similarities in character and/or life circumstances. That being said, I don't subscribe to the theory.

Comment: @Flater "No one becomes an assassin (or even just violent in general) because their life is filled with joy and happiness." Aside from those people who simply take pleasure in such activities, at least.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the previous answer, I'd like to point you to this:

http://www.cracked.com/article_20347_5-fan-theories-that-make-classic-movies-even-better.html

where it says:

> The pilot, she [Uma Thurman] says, was about a hit squad comprised of five women, called Fox Force Five, who go around killing people and telling bad jokes. It actually did sound utterly awesome, like something Tarantino should make ...
>
> The Theory:
>
> ... and he did. It's called Kill Bill.

So far, I am unaware of any official rejections to this, so, they may not be the same person, but in a way the same "character".

PS:
Something else related just popped up: [Kill Bill ending Q & U. What does that mean?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/708/kill-bill-ending-q-u-what-does-that-mean)

Comment: All this says is that other people have had the same idea as the OP.  It doesn't actually address the accuracy of that idea.

Comment: You have a point there. I actually would have put the links in a comment, and wanted to, but... alas... I cannot comment here yet! To erase the absurdity of saying this in a comment: clearly with the exception of my own posts.

Answer (score 0):

There are many theories on this. Tarantino said that a lot of his films can be watched by characters in other films. Because of this I think Kill Bill is a film set in the pulp fiction/Reservoir Dogs universe based on Mia Wallace’s failed TV show. This would explain all of the similarities between the two as well as it’s quirky style. I also think that Samuel L Jackson’s character in Kill Bill (I forgot his name) is actually Jules who’s doing one last job to leave like he wanted.